# Boolean Logic - Why doesn't the Associativity Law work in this scenario?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

By the associativity law, shouldn't the statement below be true? I understand that the truth tables are different but where exactly does the associativity law apply then if this is False?

$(p \land q) \lor r = p \land (q \lor r)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associativity is a law that applies to **one** operation. For example, associativity of addition means $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$.

Here, you have $(p \land q) \lor r = p \land (q \lor r)$. You know that these are two operations, **and** and **or**. So you can't say anything about their associativity, because associativity applies to only **one** operation.

Finally, it's easy to see that $(p \land q) \lor r = p \land (q \lor r)$ doesn't hold. Suppose $(p \land q) \lor r$ is true. Then either $r$ is true, or $(p$ and $q)$ are true, or both. So suppose only $r$ is true, and $p$ is false, so $(p \land q)$ is false. Then $(p \land q) \lor r$ is true. However, $p \land (q \lor r)$ is false, because $p$ is false, and $p$ must be true for the statement ($p$ and $(q$ or $r))$ to be true.

Comment: Haha, I'm blind. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Also try to think of it like this:

$(p \land q) \lor r$

I am going the bathroom and take a shower  or i'm eating salami

$p \land (q \lor r)$

I am going to the bathroom and I am either going to take a shower or eat salami.

Comment: Yes, you can think about it like that. Note that both cases would hold true even if you are in the bathroom, showering, and eating salami --- which is something I would discourage you from doing, even if it sounds very time-efficient.